# how do I align multiple a tags next too each other?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align multiple a tags next too each other on my navigation bar, but whenever I align them in the center they stack on top if each other. I tried disply: flex; but that aligned the text to the left

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;    
    margin: 0px -2000px;
    padding: 0px 2000px;
}

.cent {
    text-align: center;
  }
  

  .navbar a {
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;  
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>entertainment</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="entertainment.css">
        <script src="entertainment.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body> 
            
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="cent">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have `.navbar a` set to `display: block`. This causes elements to be positioned underneath eachother.

To keep the elements' block propperties but still display them next to each other, replace `block` with `inline-block`. Here is the working code snippet:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  margin: 0px -2000px;
  padding: 0px 2000px;
}

.cent {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
  
  /* This is what changed */
  display: inline-block;
  
  color: #000000;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>entertainment</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="entertainment.css">
  <script src="entertainment.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="cent">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex` with `justify-content: center` and get rid of the double div that wrapping your nav bar elements

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  margin: auto 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cent {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change display rule for `.navbar a` to `inline-block;`

```
.navbar a {
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;    
    margin: 0px -2000px;
    padding: 0px 2000px;
}

.cent {
    text-align: center;
  }
  

  .navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;  
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>entertainment</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="entertainment.css">
        <script src="entertainment.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body> 
            
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="cent">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `display: inline-block` to make everything inline.

There are some examples here - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;    
    margin: 0px -2000px;
    padding: 0px 2000px;
}

.cent {
    text-align: center;
  }
  

  .navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;  
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>entertainment</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="entertainment.css">
        <script src="entertainment.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body> 
            
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="cent">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```